# Ubuntu can't boot with secure boot disabled

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, secure-boot

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and it works fine with secure boot on. However when I disable secure boot, Ubuntu can't boot. It get stuck on the purple screen with the Ubuntu logo and white dots.

As suggested in another forum, I added the "nomodeset" option to `/etc/default/grub`

i.e. I changed

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`

then I updated grub

`$ sudo update-grub2`

However Ubuntu still cannot boot with secure boot disabled. The only difference is that the monitor has a lower resolution.

Please can you advise?

PS: I want to disable secure boot because it prevents Ubuntu from loading the NVIDIA driver.

PPS: My NVIDIA card is a GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile.

Comment: Welcome to ask Ubuntu! Consider getting rid of the `quiet splash` and trying again. It won't fix the problem, but you will see a lot of text scrolling by, and where it stops may provide a clue.

Comment: Good idea. I did that and it seems that it is a NVIDIA related problem. I get the following error. 

`[FAILED] Failed to start NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
See 'systemctl status nvidia-persistenced.service' for details`
It looks like the NVIDIA drivers cannot be loaded for some reason. I will do some research in this direction, thanks.

Comment: Some older cards are problematic. Consider editing your question and including the model # of the card,

Comment: Thanks I just did it. I also found a solution for my particular case. I'll post it here.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you sorted it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved it for me

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1064250/linux/newly-installed-drivers-are-not-found-when-nvidia-smi-is-called-/post/5389549/?offset=7#5389568

I had to uninstall the NVIDIA driver, then I was able to disable secure boot, then I reinstalled the NVIDIA driver.